# Riemann integrability in a specific situation.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration

Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[c,1]$ for all $c>0$ and that $\lim_{c\to 0} \int_c^1 f(x)dx$ exists. Additionally, assume that $\lim_{c\to 0} |f(c)|<+\infty$.

Does this mean that $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$? Intuitively this seems like it should be fine.

I am wondering if this is logically sound because I want to apply the Riemann-Lesbesgue lemma,

which states that for any Riemann integrable function $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(Nx)f(x)dx=0$,

to a function  integrable on $[-\pi,-\delta]\cup [\delta, \pi]$ for every $\delta>0$. I can show that $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} f(x)dx=0$, but does this allow me to use Riemann Lesbesgue Lemma?

Comment: No. Take $f(x) = { 1 \over \sqrt{x}}$. The issue is that $f$ is not bounded on $(0,1]$, but the improper integral exists.

Comment: I should have added this to my question: what if we also assume that $\lim_{t\to 0} |f(t)|<+\infty$. Can we now conclude $f$ is integrable?

Comment: Sure, if that is the case you can extend a partition of $[c,1]$ to a partition of $[0,1]$ without changing $L(f,P), U(f,P)$ much.

Comment: Wow, that explanation is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ to exist. You just need $f$ to be bounded on $[0,1]$.

Comment: So this means that $\sin(1/x)$ is integrable on $[0,1]$?